# connection between Azure devops and active directory

Tags: azure-devops

I've got an active directory and azure devops server 2020 on windows server . How can I connect the two? My server is not connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory works with Domain Services. See [Active Directory Domain Services Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/virtual-dc/active-directory-domain-services-overview) for details.

What you need is to **join the Windows server** which installs Azure DevOps Server **to Domain**. Please refer to [Join a Computer to a Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/join-a-computer-to-a-domain) for details.

After that it will automatically sync with the corporate domain.
However, Azure DevOps use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). So changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in Azure DevOps immediately. Instead, Azure DevOps will synchronize those groups regularly (by default every hour).

That's all required. After this, you could directly add domain users or groups to groups in Azure DevOps server.